# ORB giving lot of false matches in emgucv

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

ORB detector using Emgucv is creating a lot of false matches even after performing homography. I have used the example provided for SURF in Emgucv and replaced surf detector with ORB. Here is the result I got:

[image]

ORB in the left and SURF in the right side.How to reduce the mismatch? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Sauncu Thank u for d edit! is there any hope for my query?

Comment: You can try fitting a homography to filter outliers (assuming there are enough inliers...)

Comment: @Rosa I have tried to find the match between descriptors using " matcher.KnnMatch(observedDescriptors, matches, k, null);
                 Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(matches, uniquenessThreshold, mask);" and performed a homography check only if the above returns enough nonZero elements in the mask [emgu example code]. For ORB, the nonZero count in mask is zero, Whereas for SURF its more than 4.